# How to have several loops/ processes/ etc. occurring at the same time?

Tags: java, events, loops, process, action

While coding-- you could use Java as a reference/example, as I am most familiar with it-- how do you manage to have several "actions" happen at the same time, continually?
I understand with enough loops/booleans, you can set simple code to continually happen-- with different outputs based on various inputs-- but that isn't quite what I mean.
As far as I've learned, code has been quite sequential (which is good, but I mean purely, concretely sequential). For example, for some kind of conversion calculator: ask for input, receive input/ deal with incorrect input, convert, display, ask for another conversion/ finish.

However, for more complex codes, I would like to know how to allow for various actions/ events to happen at the same time, or the possibility of such. For example, mobile apps. allow for settings to be changed at (nearly) any given time, not waiting for a specific time in the program's run to ask for a change of settings. Likewise, video games allow for input at any given time, while other actions are still happening (such as moving while jumping and allowing for AI/enemies to interact). Yes, the code still has to follow sequences, but how do I simultaneously have various inputs/outputs or actions occur while running other processes/procedures all in the same program?

In short, the best way I can think of to describe what I am asking is: 
how do I have "multiple programs/ code" to run in one project at the same time?

Comment: Its called multithreading.. You can run several Threads(lightweight processes) simultaneously...

Comment: Read the Java Tutorial [Concurrency lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). Just be aware that threading can do your head in when you first try to wrap your mind around the concepts involved. Very experienced programmers can and do get concurrency wrong all the time, but don't get discouraged -- you have to start somewhere.

Comment: Heading in the right direction Mr. Beginner. Keep this attitude and you will learn loads :) 

Yes and what you desire for is Multi-threading. A fascinating concept.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. I will get right on it.
@Sawla, thanks for that rather uplifting comments. And yes, it does seem rather interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

What are you describing is Concurrency or multi-threading ( check out the Java docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ or this other tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html). This allows you to accomplish multiple things simultaneously by either utilizing multiple cores or quickly switching between activities to give the illusion of simultaneity. Just a few basics...To do this you create multiple Thread objects and give each thread object a Runnable object which basically is used to tell the tread what you want it to do. Every thread can only be executed once. Threads can also be put to "sleep" which means their execution will be paused for a given amount of time (An example of when you would want to do this may be if you were making a timer and you needed something to change the time on the screen as every second past.) You should also be aware that threads have the potential to throw exceptions so generally have to catch exceptions.

I have written this program as an example of threads. It will print out which thread is running then put the thread to sleep before waking and repeating 25 times for each thread.

```
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + " is running.");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    Thread a = new Thread(myRunnable, "Thread one");
    a.start();
    Thread b = new Thread(myRunnable, "Thread two");
    b.start();
}
```

Which gives the output

```
Thread one is running.
Thread one is running.
Thread two is running.
Thread two is running.
Thread one is running.
Thread two is running.
Thread one is running.
Thread one is running.
Thread two is running.
```

Notice how the output is different each time and does not progress linearly from thread one to two as you would normally be used to.